# Webpack v4 - optimization.splitChunk names incorrect

Tags: webpack

I'm in the process of migrating webpack from v3 to v4 and having some issues with the new `CommonsChunkPlugin` format.

Currently when `mode` is set to `development` all is working correctly, outputing:

`vendor.js`, `shared.js`, `default.js`, `0.js`, `1.js`, etc etc.

However when `mode` is set to `production` the `shared.js` and `vendor.js` bundles are numerically named, which means I can no longer include them on the page. These chunks used to follow the `filename` property in `output` which I need as the hashing is provided by another step for architecture reasons.

My config is as follows:

```
...
output: {
   filename: !RELEASE ? '[name].js' : '[name].js',
   chunkFilename: !RELEASE ? '[id].js' : '[id]-[chunkhash:8].js',
   jsonpFunction: '__LIB__',
   publicPath: '/content/dist/'
}
...
splitChunks: {
   name: true,
   chunks: 'async',
   cacheGroups: {
      default: false,
      commons: {
         chunks: 'initial',
         name: 'shared',
         minChunks: 2,
         maxInitialRequests: 5,
         minSize: 0
      },
      vendor: {
         test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
         name: 'vendor',
         enforce: true,
         chunks: 'all',
         minChunks: 1
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-chunk-rename-plugin

Provides seperate naming rules for certain chunks, in my case `shared.js` and `vendor.js`:

```
plugins: [
   new ChunkRenamePlugin({
      vendor: '[name].js',
      shared: '[name].js'
   }),
]
```